# Why pushdown filters doesn't improve performance for spark parquet reading from S3

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, filter, parquet

I have a question about performance with pushdown filters.
I have data stored in parquet S3 under

> s3://mybucket/data

it has 'lat', 'lon' and 'qk' columns.
There are about 750 files. Sorted by qk7 column (min value = 0230001 max value = 0233333).

When I do a simple query with spark:

```
path = "s3://mybucket/data"
prod_df = spark.read.load(path)
# not existed value in column
prod_df.where("""qk='0000000'""").count()
```

[image]

I expect a very quick spark lookup for statistics in each parquet header and 0 results since this value does not exist. However, it takes more time than scanning "real values":

```
path = "s3://mybucket/data"
prod_df = spark.read.load(path)
# real value that occures ~75000 times
prod_df.where("""qk='0230101'""").count()
```

[image]

What could be the root cause for this? I am not expecting such results